# How to add multiple audio input (CMSampleBuffer) to haishinkit using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I want to add internal and mic audio at same time while streaming to youtube using haishinkit. I am getting noisy beeps sound only while streaming.

**code used**

In case of `RPSampleBufferType.audioMic:` and `RPSampleBufferType.audioApp`, I am doing following code to append the sampleBuffer to RTMPBroadcaster class object.

```
if CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) 
{
   broadcaster.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer, withType: .audio)
}
```